# Why doesn't matplotlib save the whole figure by default?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

It's probably an issue that almost everybody who uses matplotlib would have encountered. If you generate a figure - which often contains axis labels and legends - and save it with default settings, you'll get a cropped image.

**Demo code**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot():
    plt.figure(figsize=[3,3],linewidth=5,edgecolor='r') 
    ax=plt.subplot()
    ax.plot(range(10),range(10),label='label')
    ax.set_xlabel('xlabel\nxlabel\nxlabel')
    ax.set_ylabel('ylabel\nylabel\nylabel')
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=[1,1])
plot()    
plt.savefig('no_tight_layout.png')
```

[image: no_tight_layout.png]

**(Thanks to stackoverflow), we know few workarounds but each has a caveat of its own**..
**Workaround #1:** from within matplotlib: use of **`tight_layout`** option.

```
plot()    
plt.savefig('tight_layout.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: tight_layout.png]

It works for simple figures.
**However**, in my experience, it is not reliable option in the case of more complex, multi-panel figures.
`tight_layout` often fails with errors such as these:

```
UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
UserWarning: tight_layout not applied: number of rows in subplot specifications must be multiples of one another.
```

**Workaround #2:** from outside of matplotlib: save the image in SVG format and then convert to png. For example using `--export-area-drawing` option in the **inkscape** command line UI or "resize to page" option in the inkscape's GUI.

**However**, in this case you have to depend on external softwares which are difficult to add as dependencies in python packages (currently conda only hosts Windows version of inkscape).

**So my question is..**

Why doesn't matplotlib save the whole figure by default?
If I generate the same plot in a jupyter notebook, without using `tight_layout` option, I see that all the elements of the plot are contained within the figure boundaries (shown in red).

[image: jupyter notebook]

This figure is generated in the output cell of a jupyter notebook(!).
Then why it is not saved as it is? Why the saved image is by default different from the image jupyter notebook?
In my opinion this is a very fundamental issue with matplotlib.
Would't it make the lives of the users easier, if by default, all the elements are contained in the saved figure without the need of any workarounds?

Comment: You are mixing up tight_layout with savefig=“tight” which are not the same.  Please read the tight_layout and constrained_layout tutorials to learn more about shrinking axes to fit in the figure size given.  Savefig=“tight” does the opposite and expands the figure size to fit all elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, its a feature than an issue of matplotlib. By default, matplotlib sets a fixed size for a figure, so the overflowing elements are often cropped.

There are 4 options matplotlib provides to deal with cropping of the elements:

1. `plt.subplots_adjust` manual adjustments of elements retrospectively. Figure size unchanged.
2. `plt.tight_layout` automatic adjustments. Figure size unchanged.
3. `plt.constrained_layout` automatic adjustments. Often similar to `fig.tight_layout`. Figure size unchanged.
4. `plt.savefig(..,bbox_inches='tight')`: figure size is adjusted to contain all elements as they are (what you see in jupyter notebook's outputs). Figure size changes.

Option 4 is what I needed because I wanted to save the figure as I see in jupyter notebook's output, regardless of the figure size.

I got this answer on [matplotlib's github page](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17118#issuecomment-612988008) (thanks Elan Ernest @ImportanceOfBeingErnest).