# x axis label cropped on saved image

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, savefig

So I'm trying to do a bar plot on a data where `x` is the username (string ) and each `x` is long enough to overlap each other, so I have to rotate the `x` label. No problem there. However, when exporting the plot results, the `x` label on the exported image is cropped. I tried using `plt.tight_layout()` and worked, but it change the look of the plot. The code is similar to this

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x= ['abc', 'ronaldo', 'melon_killer_123456']
y= [1, 2, 3]

plt.bar(x, y)

plt.xticks(rotation = 90) 
plt.savefig('a.png')

plt.show()
```

Exported image:

[image: wrong_image]

I want it to look like this (Got this by using jupyter notebook and manually save output image):

[image: correct_image]

So how to do that?

Comment: when I ran your supplied code I got an error, and you forgot to import matplotlib as plt

Comment: Similar to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192115/why-doesnt-matplotlib-save-the-whole-figure-by-default 
Adding plt.savefig(..,bbox_inches='tight') solved the problem for me (giving the same output as Jupyter notebooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with the rcParams size settings and the `plt.subplots_adjust` settings until you get your desired image.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x= ['abc', 'ronaldo', 'melon_killer_123456']
y= [1, 2, 3]

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5,10)
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90) 
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.925, 
                    bottom=0.20, 
                    left=0.07, 
                    right=0.90, 
                    hspace=0.01, 
                    wspace=0.01)
plt.savefig('a.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: it gives me an empty .png. Just a white space

Answer (score 2):

So i got another answer by assign a `Bbox` instance to `bbox_inches` parameter on `plt.savefig()` function. With this `Bbox` we can define `xmin`, `ymin` `xmax`and `ymax` of our saved figure (`Bbox([[xmin, ymin],[xmax, ymax]])`). The default value is `xmin=0`, `ymin=0` `xmax=figure_width`and `ymax=figure_height`

If the problem is on the bottom of the saved figure, we need just configure (lower) the `ymin`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox

x= ['abc', 'ronaldo', 'melon_killer_123456']
y= [1, 2, 3]

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90) 
plt.savefig('a.png', bbox_inches=Bbox([[0,-2],fig.get_size_inches()]))
plt.show()
```

P.s `fig.get_size_inches()` give us a list of the fig size

Comment: Please add a picture of the resulting plot